# Button Floating When Toggling Header Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a home button to the right of my header. I am also hiding a toolbar behind the header. Now when adding a home button to the header, its wont stay fixed on the header when toggling.

```
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="a.html">Settings</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="b.html">Whatever</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar -->
         <h1>Hide the Toolbar</h1>
         <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconshadow="false"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" data-transition="slide"
        data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right">home</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

$(document).bind('pageinit', function (event) {


    loadHomePage();


    $("#HomeHeader").on("click", function () {
        $("#navMainToolbar").slideToggle(200);
    });

    $("#navMainToolbar").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DMUwp/9/) of the issue.

Comment: You could move the navbar outside of the header: http://jsfiddle.net/DMUwp/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the navbar outside of the header:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a.html">Settings</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="b.html">Whatever</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /navbar -->
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Hide the Toolbar</h1>
 <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconshadow="false"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="notext"
        class="ui-btn-right">home</a>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/DMUwp/11/